# PHP Loop on every value on multidimensional array X times

Tags: php

i'm facing this problem

My code generates 2 arrays, 1 that contains a whole list of numbers that the user gives on the DOM **($item_ids)**, and another one that separates them by three **($item_sorted)**

**$item_ids**

```
[
   "1",
   "1",
   "1",
   "1",
   "1",
   "1"
]
```

**$item_sorted**

```
[
   [
      "1",
      "1",
      "1"
   ],
   [
      "1",
      "1",
      "1"
   ]
]
```

I need to go through every by 3 group on $item_sorted, and write its contents on a string like this, to make a file with that info

```
<item_ids>
1
1
1
</item_ids>
<item_ids>
2
2
2
</item_ids>
```

The "<item_ids>" gets written on my code with a .=, but all i need is to figure out how to make the loop for every x multidimensional item on that second array, like

```
    foreach group on $item_sorted{
      $mystring .= "<item_ids>"
        foreach items on group[0]{
          $mystring .= $items
          }
      $mystring .= "<item_ids>"
    }
```

Comment: The duplicate may stop having to split them at all.  But if you have to, you should move the `$mystring .= "<item_ids>"` outside the inner `foreach` loop.

Comment: @NigelRen I meant to put it on the first `foreach` loop, my bad.